# MVC Package for Java EE6?

Tags: model-view-controller, java-ee-6

I want to develop a Java EE6 application that contains some Web-GUI functionality. Suppose I do not want to use JSF and also do not want to mix in Spring. What MVC package would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Popular Java MVC frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Java)